# Visual Studio 2017 Testing Tools offline install

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2017

I made offline install for VS 2017 Testing Tools with command line using --layout PATH. But when I use created image on build server it stil want internet connection. When I did same but with VS 2017 Build Tools it works.

How I can create image for true offline instalation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was similar problem as was discused in another thread. Installation of all certificates in ./certificates folder helps

[VS2017 Enterprise offline fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685569/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-offline-installation-fails?rq=1)